# Relative import beyond top-level package Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image: I have a project named <code>tweetme</code> which has two apps <code>account</code> and <code>tweets</code>]
I have a project named `tweetme` which has two apps `account` and `tweets`,i have `serializers.py` file in both of the apps to serialize data. So when i try to relative import the serializer class from `account/api/serializers.py` to another app `tweets/api/serializers.py`, the relative import shows error.

[image]

1- 1st i tried full path `from src.account.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer`, it gave error in console that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`

[image]

2- Then i tried `from ...account.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer`,its showing error `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

So what am i doing wrong? How to do relative import properly?

@edit

adding **init**.py in src

```
    Directory: D:\django\tweetme\src


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       26-07-2018     23:56                account
d-----       25-07-2018     13:56                static-storage
d-----       25-07-2018     19:06                template
d-----       26-07-2018     19:39                tweetme
d-----       26-07-2018     10:54                tweets
-a----       25-07-2018     20:17         143360 db.sqlite3
-a----       13-07-2018     22:40            554 manage.py
-a----       27-07-2018     08:34              0 __init__.py
```

Still same error persisting...

[![User Serializer class in `account` app][4]][4]

Comment: Try to add `__init__.py` in your `src` folder.

Comment: @MadLee Sir, still its showing `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: What is the output of your `full path import` method now? Where do you run your project?

Comment: @MadLee Its the same error ` from src.account.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' `

Comment: did you added `__int__.py` to `src` folder?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak Which script do you run? And what is the path of your running script? I created a sample project but can not repeat that error.

Comment: @MadLee  Yeah,sir this is my project 

https://github.com/ChidanandaNayak/tweetme/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are missing `__init__.py` in `src` folder.
[From the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Remove all *relative imports* used from your project/app and use *absolute import*, because
**Absolute imports** are recommended, as they are usually more readable and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages) if the import system is incorrectly configured 
**Update - 1**
**1.** Change in `/tweetme/src/tweetme/urls.py`
Commented out two lines, because of their `urls.py` doesn't have any `valid patterns`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('tweets.urls')),
    path('api',include('tweets.api.urls')),
    # path('',include('account.urls')),
    # path('api',include('account.api.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**2.** Change in `/tweetme/src/tweets/api/serializers.py`
Change `from src.account.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer` to `from account.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import Tweet
from account.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer


class TweetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDisplaySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ['user', 'content']
```

Comment: Can you share your project? If so, I could look into the problem more deeply

Comment: Sir, this is my project, please have a look.. 

https://github.com/ChidanandaNayak/tweetme/tree/master/src

Comment: Thank you a lot! been struggling with that error from hours.. but one questing sir, in pycharm editor its   still showing error while importing, it says `Unresolved Reference` but in console it works fine...

Comment: This is because, you opened the `tweetme` directory from Pycharm. So Pycharm assumes it's the root directory of your project. But, Actually your root directory is (according to django peoject) `src`

Comment: Oh, so i have always open from root directory! btw Thanks a lot..for clearing my errors and confusion..